# Get URL from active Firefox session with Swift or Objective C

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift, applescript

Is it possible to retrieve the URL from an active firefox session with Swift or Objective-C. So far i was able to retrieve the Name of the actual tab with applescript but not the URL.

What would be the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not without installing something like Selenium (or, perhaps, only Selenium), AFAIK. If you do use Selenium, you can use various languages to get the "WebDriver"'s `current_url` property.
Without Selenium, if you want to get kind of clunky (but effective), you can use System Events (AppleScript) to do a command-l (ell) then command-c to highlight the url field and copy it to the clipboard, then access that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already found the solution with the copying but there are sometimes problems with different FF versions. Also I don't want the app to act that aggressive as it is disturbing. Selenium might be a solution then.

Comment: Selenium will not solve this issue. Selenium can only spawn new sessions and then you'd be able to get the active url on that session but not for a window that has been spawned by the user and not by Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

Even with Swift or ObjC, you would still need a Scripting Bridge, and Firefox's scriptability is sparse, as you have discovered.  However, AppleScript can do this with either Safari or Chrome:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    URL of tab 1 of window 1
end tell

--> "https://www.lds.org/?lang=eng"

tell application "Safari"
    URL of tab 6 of window 1
end tell

--> "http://www.nps.gov/webcams-mora/mountain.jpg"
```